# Using JQuery Ajax deferreds in a loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, deferred

I need to pass a number of items to an API via REST. I need to loop through a set of items and fire each one up to the remote API. The intent is to wait for success in between each call to the API

This is my current attempt at using JQuery's promise:

```
items.each(function(model) {
    $.when(addItem(model,endpoint)).done(function(data, xhr, results) {
        console.log('added');
  });
```

The Ajax call looks like this:

```
  addItem: function(model, endpoint) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api' + endpoint,
      type: "POST",
      headers: {
        "accept":"application/json"
      },
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        item: model.attributes.id,
        amount: model.attributes.amount
      }
    });
  }
};
```

When the code runs over a number of times in the loop, I get some items being stored, some giving back a 500 response and some giving back a 409 (duplicate) response. I can manually add the items to the API without a problem. It might just be that the loop is running too quickly for the API but it could be my code. I know there are better ways to add the items but at the moment I have to use this loop idea for testing until a future iteration of API code.

Does the above look correct, or is there a better way to tackle this?

Comment: I would suggest passing a callback function to your additem / ajax call, rather than attempting to do the `when`, but I'm curious what others have to say...

Comment: @cale_b: That's probably the best approach. The tricky part comes from iterating through the models in that asynchronous fashion. My answer uses `jQuery.Deferred#always` rather than passing in the callback, but I think it more or less follows the spirit of what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

You can either chain your AJAX calls by recursively calling them on success of your AJAX call or you could make the calls synchronous (by making use of `async: false`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api' + endpoint,
    type: "POST",
    async: false, 
    headers: {
      "accept":"application/json"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      item: model.attributes.id,
      amount: model.attributes.amount
    }
});
```

Please note making it synchronous will block any other Javascript from running as Javascript is single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to attach the callbacks in sequence with careful use of recursion in the Deferred callbacks. Here's one possible implementation:

```
// I'm paranoid about making sure basic prototype functions are available
// even if some library clobbers the original definition later.
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

// This function should be `.apply`'d with the array of models you need to add.
// It will call `addItem` on the first argument, and then use this function as
// a callback to `addItem` with the arguments shifted by one.
var invokeAddItem = function (modelToAdd) {
    var rest = slice.call(arguments, 1);

    addItem(modelToAdd, endpoint).always(function () {
        invokeAddItem.apply(null, rest);
    });
};

invokeAddItem.apply(null, items);    // Equivalent to `invokeAddItem(items[0], ...)`
```